# Rails/Rspec - testing a redirect in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, rspec, routes

So I am currently writing a test for a controller in an existing controller that just didn't have one before. What I want to test is a redirect that happens when someone is not allowed to edit something vs someone that is allowed to edit it.

the controller action being edit

```
def edit
  if !@scorecard.reviewed? || admin?
    @company = @scorecard.company
    @custom_css_include = "confirmation_page"
  else
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

So if a scorecard has been reviewed then only an admin can edit that score.
The routes for that controller..

```
# scorecards
resources :scorecards do
  member do
    get 'report'
  end
  resources :inaccuracy_reports, :only => [:new, :create]
end
```

and finally the test

```
  require 'spec_helper'

  describe ScorecardsController do

    describe "GET edit" do
      before(:each) do
        @agency = Factory(:agency)
        @va = Factory(:va_user, :agency => @agency)
        @admin = Factory(:admin)
        @company = Factory(:company)
        @scorecard = Factory(:scorecard, :level => 1, :company => @company, :agency => @agency, :reviewed => true)
        request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = "/scorecard"
      end

      context "as a admin" do
        before(:each) do
          controller.stub(:current_user).and_return @admin
        end

        it "allows you to edit a reviewed scorecard" do
          get 'edit', :id => @scorecard.id
          response.status.should be(200)
        end
      end

      context "as a va_user" do
        before(:each) do
        controller.stub(:current_user).and_return @va
      end

      it "does not allow you to edit a reviewed scorecard" do
        get 'edit', :id => @scorecard.id
        response.should redirect_to :back
      end
    end
  end
end
```

so a va when trying to edit a reviewed score will be redirected back, where an admin won't.

but when running this through rspec I get

```
ScorecardsController
  GET edit
    as a admin
      allows you to edit a reviewed scorecard
    as a va_user
      does not allow you to edit a reviewed scorecard (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) ScorecardsController GET edit as a va_user does not allow you to edit a reviewed scorecard
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to :back
   Expected response to be a redirect to </scorecard> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/>
     # ./spec/controllers/scorecards_controller_spec.rb:33:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.48517 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

so I don't know if its working or not since I set the `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = "/scorecard"` as the place that should be the `:back` as it where. or am I missing the idea all together looking at [httpstatus](http://httpstatus.es/) there are the 300 responses that I could use but I wouldn't know where to start?

any help would be awesome

### EDIT

I could test it by doing it like this

```
...
response.status.should be(302)
```

but I got the idea from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040479/rspec-testing-redirect-to-back) and it sounds like this could be powerful as it specifies the url redirected to.

Anyone have a working test like this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This line has problem

```
response.should redirect_to :back
```

The logic is not correct. You should expect `#edit` to redirect to `:back` path you set before, which is `/scorecard`. But you set `:back` here. In the context of Rspec, `:back` should be empty at each example.

To revise, just set it as

```
response.should redirect_to '/scorecard'
```

Comment: thats what i tried first . 

`1) ScorecardsController GET edit as a va_user does not allow you to edit a reviewed scorecard`
     `Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to '/scorecard'`
`Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/scorecard> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/>`

Comment: I see. How about you try to put `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = "/scorecard"` into the example instead of before. I'm afraid this var will get lost.

Comment: `it "does not allow you to edit a reviewed scorecard" do
      request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = "/scorecard"
      get 'edit', :id => @scorecard.id
      response.should redirect_to "/scorecard"
     end`
then id still get the same error man this is hard to get right.

Comment: This should not be hard, I used similar pattern before. Please check if you have some filter in `/scorecard`. In your `get edit`, you act like a normal visitor without login, I'm afraid you are not allowed to view /scorecard page as well, and then be redirected to homepage further.

Comment: Latest rspec syntax: expect(response).to redirect_to '/scorecard'

Answer (score 90):

To make the test more readable you can do this:
(rspec ~> 3.0)

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(action_path)
```

Comment: Or you can do only the action name, without the '_path'

Comment: @MateusLuiz Couldn't you please write any example?

Comment: @yivo like this: expect(response).to redirect_to :new_registration

Answer (score 4):

For testing if redirects happened, with no matching route

(just to test redirection, i used this when route is too long :D ).
You can simply do like:

```
expect(response.status).to eq(302) #redirected
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not returning a `response`.  If you end up in this situation, you can do:

`expect(page.current_path).to eql('expected/path')`